# Why can't Safari connect to the sever "localhost"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, localhost

I am learning Ruby on rails from a PDF  on ruby.railstutorial.org. I have been learning for about a week and a half now and have not had any trouble until yesterday. I was building a sample app and tried to look at some results in the browser but for some reason it says 'safari can't open page "localhost:3000/static_pages/home" because Safari cannot connect to the server "localhost".

- I am on OS X Mavericks 10.9.2

Comment: I fixed it, i was using the Micheal Hartl rails tutorial and my routes file had some un-needed code

Answer (score 3):

Try `http://0.0.0.0:3000`. 
That works for me.
Not sure why Safari doesn't like localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Try `127.0.0.1`, enable web sharing in System Preferences, and if running, turn off Apache.

[Source](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22326768#22326768)

Comment: i have tried 127.0.0.1 and it did the same thing as just typing in localhost. Mavericks does not have an "enable web sharing" option so i clicked "enable internet sharing", it did not fix it. Do you know the command that would turn off apache i tried 'sudo launchtl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist' it says that launchtl command was not found

Comment: Try `sudo apachectl stop`

Answer (score 0):

Is your Rails server running? If not, launch it with `rails s` from the sample_app folder in Terminal. Alternatively, if it is running, quit it with `ctrl+c` and then start it again with the first command.